# twisted ordered DeferredList

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted

Is it possible to create a `DeferredList` (or anything similar) that runs all the deferred in a defined order ?

I need to run a list of deferred, but ideally the deferred should wait on the previous one, as it can alter the next deferred result:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""

"""

from __future__ import division, absolute_import, \
    print_function, unicode_literals

from twisted.internet import defer, reactor


def multiply(n):
    if n == 3:
        import time
        time.sleep(1)
    print(n * 10)
    return n * 10


def stopIfResultIsAbove20(n):
    if n > 20:
        print('result is above 20, i would like to stop the following deferreds')
        raise Exception('The result is above 20, cancelling the other deferreds')
    return n


def onSuccess(result):
    print(result)
    return result


def onError(failure):
    print('failed !')
    pass

requests = []
for n in range(0, 6):
    d = defer.Deferred()
    d.addCallback(multiply)
    d.addCallback(stopIfResultIsAbove20)
    if n == 3:
        from twisted.internet import threads
        threads.deferToThread(d.callback, n)
    else:
        reactor.callLater(0, d.callback, n)
    requests.append(d)

dl = defer.DeferredList(requests,
                        fireOnOneErrback=True)
dl.addCallbacks(onSuccess, onError)
dl.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())

reactor.run()
```

What I would like to do:

- create multiple deferreds
- each following deferred wait on previous one
- if previous one had result > 20, stop all the chain

EDIT: I can achieve this with the `@inlineCallback` decorator and make the code *synchronous*, but I've read that `@inlineCallbacks` should be avoided, so I'd like to achieve this with a traditional deferred code

Comment: @inlineCallback doesn't make code synchronous.  It is a hack that used in other asynchronous frameworks to write sequential ansynchronous code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with `@inlineCallbacks`.  The reason you've been told to avoid `@inlineCallbacks` is that it's far too easy to make your code accidentally sequential like this; when you're using `Deferred`s you usually want parallelism, and sometimes it's hard to notice you've given it up if your code looks blocking.  However, if you understand how it works, `@inlineCallbacks` is fine whenever you want to use it; and if you actually *want* sequential behavior like this, `@inlineCallbacks` is perfect.

Comment: I see, and after searching through Twisted documentation I found out the `task.Cooperator`, it seemed to achieve exactly what I needed to do. Would you rather use `@inlineCallbacks` or `Cooperator` to achieve this ?

Comment: Either one is OK; it's more of a stylistic choice at that point.